# Sleep after every third iteration in the 'for loop'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I'm trying to make my script sleep after every third iteration in the 'for loop'. This is what I have so far:

```
 #List of words
 Word_list = ['apple','orange','grape','mango','berries','banana','sugar']

 #Loop through the list of words with the index and value of the list
 for i,word in enumerate(Word_list):
     #Store value of i in v
     v = i
     #If the value of the index, same as the 3rd loop iteration is 3, do this
     if v == 3*(i+1):
       sleep(3)
       print(i+1,word,'done')
     #Else do this
     else:
       print('exception')
```

The output is not what I expected though.

Expected output is:

```
exception
exception
3,grape,done
exception
exception
6,banana,done
exception
```

Comment: `if v%3==0:` checks if `v` is a multiple of 3. `v = i; if v == 3*(i+1):` is `False` for every integer `i`.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist, thanks but your answer gives `1,apple, done` as the first output, which is not my intention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. Doing `v = i` and then checking `v == 3 * (i + 1)` will always gives False since you are checking `i==3*(i+1)` which is true for `i=-1/2`

```
import time
Word_list = ['apple','orange','grape','mango','berries','banana','sugar']
#Loop through the list of words with the index and value of the list
for i,word in enumerate(Word_list, 1):
    #modulus function checks for divisibility by 3
    if (i %3 == 0):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i,word,'done')
    #Else do this
    else:
       print('exception')
```

Comment: Or just use `for i, word in enumerate(Word_List, 1)` and remove addition from IF statement `if i % 3 == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Your condidtion of your `if` statement isn't doing what you want it to do. `v` will never equal `3*(i+1)` because you set `i=v` earlier in the loop. What you want to do is the modulus of `v` by 3 where it will be equal to 0 that way you know it has been three times looping through the list. This is what the code should look like

```
import time
#List of words
Word_list = ['apple','orange','grape','mango','berries','banana','sugar']

#Loop through the list of words with the index and value of the list
for i,word in enumerate(Word_list):
    #Store value of i in v
    v = i
    #If the value of the index, same as the 3rd loop iteration is 3, do this
    if (v + 1) %3 == 0:
        time.sleep(3)
        print(i+1,word,'done')
    #Else do this
    else:
        print('exception')
```

which gives this output:

```
exception
exception
3 grape done
exception
exception
6 banana done
exception
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a variant:

```
from time import sleep

Word_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'mango', 'berries', 'banana', 'sugar']

# Loop through the list of words with the index and value of the list
for i, word in enumerate(Word_list, start=1):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        sleep(3)
        print(i, word, 'done')
    else:
        print('exception')
```

the trick is to start the enumeration at `1` and check if `i%3` is zero.